# What are the differences between the empty object type and Object?

Tags: types, typescript

I've noticed that TypeScript supports using the following types:

- `{}` (referred to in the specs as *Empty Object Type*)
- `Object`

They both seem to be equivalent and interchangeable as far as I can tell. What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 3):

Within the context of TypeScript, there is no practical difference but there is a semantic difference. All the members of the `Object` are implicitly present on *all* objects.

`{}` means something that has no members of its own. {} would still have all the members of `Object`. So they are interchangeable in TypeScript.

```
// Extend ALL objects
interface Object{
    baz:number;
}

var foo:{} = {};
var bar:Object = {};

foo.baz = 123;
bar.baz = 123;
```

Personally I haven't ever *declared* a variable to be one of these. Perhaps you should use `any` which is something that is compatible with *everything*.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any reference to confirm this?

Comment: It's interesting that you use `any` instead of `Object` or `{}`. I can understand not using `{}`, since it looks funny and its semantics don't seem generally useful, from what you've said. However, I find it more readable to use `Object` if I expect a set of name-value pairs provided as an object, for example. Using `any` in that case would be less readable to me, since it would imply, from a readability perspective, that passing in a `number` or other primitive is OK.

Comment: If you use `{}` or `Object` e.g. `foo:Object` you cannot do `foo.yourProperty = 123`.

Answer (score 0):

I've always understood it as `Object` refers to the JavaScript object type. Commonly used as `{}` or sometimes `new Object`.

I believe they are equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

As *type annotations*, both `{}` and `Object` refer to the same type, the Empty Object Type. However, `{}` can serve also as an object *literal*, equivalent to `new Object`.