# Typescript empty object and any difference

Tags: typescript

Could somebody explain me which is the difference between `{}` and `any`?

for example, which's the difference between setting generic interface parameter as `Interface<{}>` or as `Interface<any>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396195/what-are-the-differences-between-the-empty-object-type-and-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript any vs Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object)

Comment: Using `{}` is really a javascript thing, because in JS you don't have types. In Typescript you can define a type (by using `type`, `class` or `interface`) and then you can define your object to be of that type.

Answer (score 5):

to better understand what does `{}` mean, check https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type

`{}` is a top type. What does it mean ? if you annotate something as `{}` it can be any of following types: `string | number | boolean | object | {[key:string]: any} | Object | any[]`

```
const test1: {} = 'hello'
const test2: {} = 123
const test3: {} = false
const test4: {} = {foo:'bar'}
```

Although `null | undefined` is not allowed

```
// Expect errors
const test6: {} = null
const test7: {} = undefined
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20test1%3A%20%7B%7D%20%3D%20%27hello%27%0D%0Aconst%20test2%3A%20%7B%7D%20%3D%20123%0D%0Aconst%20test3%3A%20%7B%7D%20%3D%20false%0D%0Aconst%20test4%3A%20%7B%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%27bar%27%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20test5%3A%20%7B%7D%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0D%0Aconst%20test6%3A%20%7B%7D%20%3D%20null%0D%0Aconst%20test7%3A%20%7B%7D%20%3D%20undefined)

`any` completely turns off type checker and you can do anything "crazy", that you've been used to from vanilla JS. PRO TIP: don't use this at home :) definitely use `no-any` rule within ts-lint

Comment: This seems right but where in the docs does it explicitly state those types above are compatible? Can't seem to find that anywhere...

Comment: there is no mention in the docs as there is new "replacement" as a public API from typescript - called `unknown` which should be used instead.

- So `{}` was former bottom type (rather private API of TS)
- since introduction of `unknown` , `unknown` is the new bottom type and should be used only

Answer (score -3):

So there are types in JavaScript. Like `number`, `string`, `object` and `boolean`. `any` matches any of these types. `{}` just matches an empty `object`.

```
function fn1(foo: any): void {}
function fn2(foo: {}): void {}

fn1(23); // OK
fn1('test'); // OK
fn1(undefined); // OK
fn2({}); // OK
fn2(23); // Not OK
fn2(null); // Not OK
```

Comment: `any` is not just another type, `any` suppresses typechecking: `function f(): any {  };  let a = f(); a.whatever.ever.ever()` compiles without errors.

Comment: It seems that `{}` does actually not just match an empty object, but seems to rather be equivalent to `object`. So your example `fn2(23)` does actually not cause any error.