# What does this type annotation mean

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```js
    private getJsonBody(body: {}|FormData) {
        return !(body instanceof FormData) ? JSON.stringify(body) : body;
    }
```

What do the open+close curly braces mean as a type? In the current environment I'm using this doesn't compile and I have to change it to `any` to get it to work.

Comment: It's an object type with no known properties, also known as the "empty object type".  It matches just about anything.  Only `null` and `undefined` may not be assigned to it.

Comment: So why would I get a compiler error about something like: "Object PersonViewModel cannot be assigned to type {}" (the wording may be incorrect on that, I don't have the code to hand right now)

Comment: No idea, you probably need to post a [mcve] for someone to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript empty object and any difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339869/typescript-empty-object-and-any-difference)

Comment: 1) You should have referenced the version of Typescript you are on. 2) [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339065/typescript-empty-object-for-a-typed-variable) may provide an alternate solution with `Partial<FormData>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an `Empty Object Type`.

It describes an object that has no members on its own. TypeScript issues a compile-time error when you try to access arbitrary properties on such an object:

```
// Type {}
const obj = {};

// Error: Property 'prop' does not exist on type '{}'.
obj.prop = "value";
```

However, you can still use all properties and methods defined on the Object type, which are implicitly available via JavaScript's prototype chain:

```
// Type {}
const obj = {};

// "[object Object]"
obj.toString();
```

- Source: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-object-type-in-typescript#the-empty-type

---

Relevant info is [Basarat's Lazy Object Initialization](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/lazyObjectLiteralInitialization.html) entry that explains how Typescript will refuse this process and how to work with it.

Using that entry you would need to change your code in this manner:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
  baz: number;
}

private getJsonBody(body: {} as Foo | FormData) {
  return !(body instanceof FormData)
    ? JSON.stringify(body)
    : body;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me - I was investigating why my openapi generated lib wasn't compiling and it's to do with the service class allowing a null request, but the HttpClient asking for {}