# Typescript ignores wrong return type when using outside type

Tags: typescript

The following snipped allows action to return a string:

```
type Action = () => { error?: any };

const action: Action = () => {
   if (Math.random()) {
        return {}
    };

    return "" // ?
}
```

But not the following:

```
const action = (): { error?: any } => {
   if (Math.random()) {
        return {}
    };

    return "" // Error
}
```

Would love an explanation as this error has me desperate. Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggYxASwPYDsYF4YAoCU2AfDAN4xQBOlqlA-AFwwCG6YMAvgNzDAIYBnECyRp0TRCgzYYeQlhKlgsmMgBmeALLMQACwB0lVgBNUAWwKElKmzEpQQAV0qZSHZSu68b9py5gARAHA7nyCwsyiGABCMgRM5FQ09Eys7BzEZB6qGrjaeoYm5pZZtiq+zq7uNl7Zdg6VgQEwAPQtMACi1LQhQA).

Comment: Curious! I think is related to the fact that [the `{}` type is a bit of a strange thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339869/typescript-empty-object-and-any-difference) and `{ error?: any }` is almost that type. And there are slightly different semantics for dealing with typing a whole function vs typing just the return value. Maybe something [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WJyBDm) could work?

Comment: The top infers to `() => {}`, since `''` is assignable to `{}`. That in turn is assignable to `() => { error?: any }`. In the other case, you set the return type explicitly, and `''` is not assignable to `{ error?: any }`. Seems to be an... unfortunate effect of the peculiarities around `{}`.

Comment: Strangely, you get this error with both of your examples in the playground if you turn them from arrow to regular functions

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection). Typescript will not let you return any value which has no overlap with the return type of the function. To mitigate it you can do the following: `return "" as {error?: any}` or `return "" as Action`

Comment: I think that OP's question is more about why is the weak type detection applied when you declare the return type inside the function but not when the type is defined above in the code