# What is meaning of T = {} in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-generics

I m pretty fine with typescript but never understand what this syntax mean,

```
function cool<T = {}>() {
           // do something
}
```

but what is the significance of `<T = {}>`, can't we simply use `<T>`, what benefit does it provide?

Comment: It's the default type for the generic type parameter, so you can call `cool()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is a generic type parameter. `=` in this context is used to specify a default value for `T`, which in this case is an empty object type. Setting a default value for a type parameter makes it optional, just like with normal parameters. So if you don't provide the type argument `T` on invocation it will default to `{}`.

Comment: Note `{}` isn't an empty object here, it's the empty object _type_ - https://stackoverflow.com/q/21396195/3001761.